# How do I get CSS Grid column widths to match the content?

Tags: css, css-grid

**My problem:** I can't figure out how to get CSS grid track widths to auto-size to image content.

Here's **[my CodePen](https://codepen.io/simspace-dev/pen/bLQpxJ)** that shows the problem I describe below:

I have several `<div>` elements using the same CSS class which defines a CSS grid.

Each `<div>` element represents a row that can contain a varying number of images. The image widths will be the same per row, there will not be rows of mixed image widths.

One row may contain two images that are `178px` wide.

Another row may contain five images that are `133px` wide.

I want the gap between all columns to be `10px` wide. However, as seen in my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/simspace-dev/pen/bLQpxJ), all the columns in each row end up `178px` wide. The grid tracks with the `133px` images end up `178px` wide creating a huge gap.

Can this be done with one CSS grid class? Or do I need to define different CSS grid classes for the different width images?

Comment: Not too familiar with css grid yet. Been meaning to check this out: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/03/a-new-css-grid-demo-on-mozilla-org/

Comment: Essentially, **you don't have a grid**...you have rows with different width columns...that's not a grid.

Comment: @Paulie_D, except it is using CSS grid as defined by `display: grid`. 
True that, for now it may be one row of images, but add more rows and it's a grid.

Comment: No...a grid has defined vertical columns that apply to ALL rows...that is not the case here (which is the issue). Adding a `display:grid` doesn't make it an *actual* grid.

Comment: @Paulie_D, so if it were a single column, would it be defined as a grid? 
And if I added another row, would it be defined as a grid?

Comment: If it's a single column then yes it could be a grid...and as long as the second row was also a single column it could be a grid. A grid, as I said, has column widths that apply to all rows.

Comment: @Paulie_D, thanks for your input! Now you've got me questioning my understanding of the CSS grid based on the MSN docs. If I am misunderstanding the docs, I'd appreciate some clarity. 

I agree that visually one see's a row. But I think, technically it is one row with multiple columns. Add more images, enough to exceed the width of the browser and rows of images are created by wrapping. Or just resize the browser for the same effect. ...

Comment: According to MSN docs a grid is " ... an intersecting set of horizontal and vertical lines – one set defining columns and the other rows." If you view the elements in my Codepen with the browser's devtools it recognizes the single row as a grid with intersecting horizontal and vertical line ... one row with multiple columns.

The MSN docs go on further to say "We create a `grid` container by declaring `display: grid` or `display: inline-grid` on an element. As soon as we do this all direct children of that element will become `grid` items."

Comment: The docs also explain the you can define an **explicit** grid using `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` or in **implicit** grid using `grid-template-columns` and the `repeat()` notation which is what I am doing.   

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout

Comment: A single row (in your case) can be a grid but if the columns don't match the second row (which they don't) then your two rows aren't a **unified** grid...See my point? They're two *separate* gridw since the vertical lines aren't the same for both.

Comment: Gotcha! That makes sense. Hopefully this conversation will help others who stumble upon it.  Thanks @Paulie_D.

Answer (score 5):

You would need to define different CSS grid classes for the different width images.

```css
.items-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(133px, 178px));
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.items-grid2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(128px, 133px));
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="items-grid">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/178x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/178x100">
</div>

<div class="items-grid2">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/133x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/133x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/133x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/133x100">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/133x100">
</div>
```

Comment: Remember the browser stores the calculated widths in memory and since the same class is used - you get the same css treatment, thus the "bug" you have.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I was hoping there was a trick I was not aware of. Thank you!